# How was this made?

Tags: android

This screen was captured from Gmail app for android. The popup looks pretty cool with images and all. Any ideas on how this was made?

[image]

Comment: That's probably a normal activity with a transparent, black background. They probably set `Theme.Translucent` in the manifest for the activity and added the transparent background via `android:background` to the root element of the activity.

Comment: @alextsc Normal activity with webview?

Comment: Can't tell, maybe. Maybe just a button and a bunch of ImageViews. But both could work.

Comment: @alextsc I'll try both thanks. Btw what do you use for displaying credits in your app?

Comment: I don't have a published app in the market, so I can't answer that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is done with a custom dialog, it is actually quite easy to achieve. Just create a layout for a normal Activity and pass it to the Dialog builder.

For more information, check http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog out

Comment: Oh and I just saw that in your picture there is actually no border, so it is probably *not* done with a custom dialog. However, I think it is more practical to use it.

Comment: screenshot from http://developer.android.com doesn't look like the one from gmail btw..

Comment: @BinoyBabu: Well, if you don't set the title like they've done in the example, you can get very close to the screenshot above.

Comment: is there a translucent theme for custom dialog?

Comment: You could apply some of these values (eg. background color): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android/2700683#2700683